# Is "leadering" an actual word?

Tags: conjugation, non-native-english

I've seen it used by non-native English speakers as some form of leadership infinitive (not sure why it is not just "leading") but I am not sure if it as actual word (or special form or conjugation).

I've seen it used for example like: "Diploma in leadering"

Comment: Just about any noun in English can be verbed (cf. "I'm going to science the shit out of this" in the movie *The Martian*), but this usage sounds rather ham-fisted to me.

Comment: That example doesn't make much sense even if we allow "leader" as a verb.

Comment: Just edited the example, Was trying to find direct translation of "diplomado" when it refers to a course/certification

Comment: What is the (Spanish?) word you're trying to translate into "leadering"?

Comment: I guess it is "Liderazgo"

Comment: Try "leadership" then.

Comment: In the world of roof drainage, there are gutters and leaders, which constitute the guttering and leadering. For an audience in parts of the U.S. where (a) people own houses and (b) have rain to contend with, a “Doctor of Leadering” would suggest some kind of home maintenance outfit, like *Professor Turf* or *Termite-B-Gone*.

Answer (score 1):

The word is essentially verbing the noun **leader**. Existentially, it is as much a word as you want to consider it to be; actually, I haven't found it in any dictionary and usage appears rare, so in most situations readers would find it either unusual or awkward.

For example, here are a couple of hits I've found in academic literature:

Massengale, J.D. (1995). Visionary leadership and the physical educator. *Physical Educator*, 52(4), 219-222. (Found via [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)):

> There are literally thousands (Bass, 1990) of studies that report the characteristics of leadership, and what leaders are always like. The literature suggests that competent leaders are always bright, seem to seek responsibility and authority, display skills at whatever they are " **leadering** " in, seem to display a contagious enthusiasm, are always perceived to possess a tremendous capacity for hard work, and have a great sense of humor most of the time.

Luskin, R. (1987). [Measuring political sophistication](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2111227). *American Journal of Political Science*, 31(4), 856-899. doi:10.2307/2111227

> Few people toe any party of factional line absolutely, but since cue taking saves effort, most do engage in some **follow-the-leadering** of this sort.

Both uses feel invented for the occasion: Massengale puts his usage in quotes, and Luskin marks his own invention (building off of the children's game "follow the leader") with hyphens. Furthermore, like some examples of *verbing* (more information in "[Do You Even Language, Bro?](https://daily.jstor.org/in-which-we-science-why-nouns-become-verbs-because-language/)"), the meaning is easy enough to guess: *leadering* means acting as a leader, and *follow-the-leadering* means acting like in the game *follow the leader* to line up (literally or figuratively) behind someone else.

Save for the extra flair of academic style, then, you would want to consider whether similar words would be clearer for your audience, like *leadership* or *leading*.

Comment: Not convinced it [the first example] is academic style so much as tongue-in-cheeking. Excellent explanation though.